# Why thread code is not executed?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, delphi-xe2

I have 4 threads created at runtime. Each thread enters critical section, changes global variable, exits critical section and shows message dialog with the result. OnThreadTerminate I also have a message dialog. It seems to be random, but still, I sometimes get 3 messages with the result and one saying that thread is terminated. How is it even possible? Win7 x64.[image]
There is my full code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  IdThreadComponent, idHTTP, SyncObjs;

const
  THREAD_NAME = 'MyidThreadComponent';

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
    FGlobalVariable: integer;
    procedure CreateThreads(const ACount: integer; const AStart: boolean);
    function GetWebsiteContent(const AURL: string): string;
    procedure MyIdThreadComponentOnRunHandler(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
    procedure MyIdThreadComponentOnTerminateHandler(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    property GlobalVariable: integer read FGlobalVariable write FGlobalVariable;
    property CriticalSection: TCriticalSection read FCriticalSection;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FCriticalSection);
end;

function TForm1.GetWebsiteContent(const AURL: string): string;
var
  _MyidHTTP: TidHTTP;
begin
  _MyidHTTP := TidHTTP.Create(self);
  try
    Result := _MyidHTTP.Get(AURL);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(_MyidHTTP);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyIdThreadComponentOnRunHandler(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var
  _LocalVariable: integer;
begin
  CriticalSection.Acquire;
  try
    // Safe way to deal with global variables. Only one thread will enter
    // CriticalSection at time.
    _LocalVariable := GlobalVariable;
    _LocalVariable := _LocalVariable * 2;
    GlobalVariable := _LocalVariable;
  finally
    CriticalSection.Release;
  end;
  ShowMessage(Sender.Name + ' started: ' + IntToStr(_LocalVariable));
  Sender.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyIdThreadComponentOnTerminateHandler
  (Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  ShowMessage(Sender.Name + ' terminated.');
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GlobalVariable := 1;
  CreateThreads(4 { System.CPUCount + 1 } , true);
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateThreads(const ACount: integer; const AStart: boolean);
var
  _MyIdThreadComponent: TIdThreadComponent;
  i: integer;
begin
  if ACount > 0 then
    for i := 1 to ACount do
    begin
      _MyIdThreadComponent := FindComponent(THREAD_NAME + IntToStr(i))
        as TIdThreadComponent;
      if not Assigned(_MyIdThreadComponent) then
      begin
        _MyIdThreadComponent := TIdThreadComponent.Create(self);
        _MyIdThreadComponent.Name := THREAD_NAME + IntToStr(i);
        _MyIdThreadComponent.Tag := i;
        _MyIdThreadComponent.OnRun := MyIdThreadComponentOnRunHandler;
        _MyIdThreadComponent.OnTerminate :=
          MyIdThreadComponentOnTerminateHandler;
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
        _MyIdThreadComponent.Priority := tpNormal;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
        _MyIdThreadComponent.Priority := 1;
{$ENDIF}
      end;
      if AStart = true then
        if Assigned(_MyIdThreadComponent) then
          _MyIdThreadComponent.Start;
    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Try synchronizing the UI calls to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You _really_ shouldn't update the GUI except on the main thread.

Comment: ShowMessage() is not thread-safe and must not be called outside of the main UI thread. Use Windows.MessageBox() instead, it is thread-safe and can be called in a worker thread.

Answer (score 2):

Showmessage is not the best way to show the output as its not thread safe.  Instead, if you use a memo or other control and wrap it in a synchronize call it will be easier to see the results.  I modified your routine to output to a memo, and included the ThreadId before and inside the synchronize call so you can better understand what is happening.

Keep in mind that your threads will not always output in the order you may think they will, it is entirely possible that thread 4 will output before thread 1, even though thread 1 was started first and 4 last.

```
procedure TForm13.MyIdThreadComponentOnRunHandler(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var
  _LocalVariable: integer;
  _LocalThreadId : Cardinal;
begin
  fCriticalSection.Acquire;
  try
    // Safe way to deal with global variables. Only one thread will enter
    // CriticalSection at time.
    _LocalVariable := GlobalVariable;
    _LocalVariable := _LocalVariable * 2;
    GlobalVariable := _LocalVariable;
  finally
    fCriticalSection.Release;
  end;
  _LocalThreadId := TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID;
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,procedure begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%s Started (%d/%d): %d',[Sender.Name,_LocalThreadId,TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID,_LocalVariable]));
  end);
  Sender.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm13.MyIdThreadComponentOnTerminateHandler
  (Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  // note sync call is not needed as this is executed in the context of the main thread.
  memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%s terminated. (%d)',[Sender.Name,TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID]));
end;
```